# Session error on php 7

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2, php-7

when I update my local host to php 7 , I have this two errors on session , I dont know its local setting on php.ini problem or my codes need update.

errors is :

```
[warn] #204 in lib/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php
session_write_close(): Session callback expects true/false return value
```

and

```
[warn] #204 in lib/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php
session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session)
```

Comment: Did you do as the error message suggested and verify that the session path exists and is writable by PHP?

Comment: The problem seems to be basically the same as the one the user in the linked question is having.  PHP 7 requires session handlers to return values that weren't required in PHP 5, so you'll either have to wait for Zend to update its session handler, switch to a PHP 7 compatible handler or modify Zend session yoruself